# Create ToJSON instance for persistent Entity

Tags: haskell, yesod

I'm trying to use the new `selectRep` function from Yesod 1.2, but I'm having trouble getting json responses to work.

```
instance ToJSON (Entity Feed) where
    toJSON (Entity uid (Feed url lastUpdated)) = object 
        [ "id" .= uid
        , "url" .= url
        , "lastUpdated" .= lastUpdated
        ]

getFeedByIdR :: FeedId -> Handler TypedContent
getFeedByIdR feedId = do
    feed <- runDB $ get404 feedId
    selectRep $ do
        provideRep $ return $ toJSON (Entity feedId feed)
```

The error I get from the above code is

```
Handler/Feed.hs:23:31:
    Overlapping instances for ToJSON (Entity Feed)
      arising from a use of `toJSON'
    Matching instances:
      instance ToJSON e => ToJSON (Entity e)
        -- Defined in `persistent-1.2.0.1:Database.Persist.Class.PersistEntity'
      instance ToJSON (Entity Feed) -- Defined at Handler/Feed.hs:5:10
    In the second argument of `($)', namely
      `toJSON (Entity feedId feed)'
    In the second argument of `($)', namely
      `return $ toJSON (Entity feedId feed)'
    In a stmt of a 'do' block:
      provideRep $ return $ toJSON (Entity feedId feed)
```

It seems that persistent does indeed provide an instance for `ToJSON (Entity e)` [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/persistent/1.2.0.1/doc/html/src/Database-Persist-Class-PersistEntity.html), but can I use my `ToJSON (Entity Feed)` somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual trick for overriding default `instance`s (which is what Yesod's `ToJSON e => ToJSON (Entity e)` instance is) is to use a `newtype`.

```
newtype EntityFeed = EF (Entity Feed)
instance ToJSON EntityFeed where ...
```

though that might be a little inconvenient.

Answer (score 5):

If you provide an instance for `Feed`, then you can use the built-in `Entity e` instance. Adding `json` to your entity line will create that instance automatically, see:
https://github.com/yesodweb/persistent/wiki/Persistent-entity-syntax#json-instances

Comment: Looks like nowadays `Entity a` doesn't have a `ToJSON` instance but one can use [`entityIdToJSON`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/persistent-2.13.1.2/docs/Database-Persist-Class-PersistEntity.html#v:entityIdToJSON), for example.

Answer (score 0):

As tel said, you could use `newtype` to define a different type and circumvent the restriction. However, if using a new type is too inconvenient, you could also use the language extension `OverlappingInstances`.

This extension allows you to have overlapping instances as long as there is always one more specific then the other (which will be chosen if it matches).

(See http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/haskell-prime/wiki/OverlappingInstances)